# HPE V1910 48 Gig Port Question

Tags: vlan

I have a question. I have an HPE V1910 48 Gig Switch. I am looking to combine 2 ports on the switch so that I can get a 2 Gig Ethernet connection to my PC. I can not figure out how to do this. can someone please help?

Thanks,

Comment: Be aware that you will never be able to have a single data flow higher than 1Gb/s. Link aggregation technologies allow to balance several flow over several links (I.E. you can have 2 flows both running at 1Gbs/s).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

this switch is Comware based, so you would need to set up a Bridge-Aggregation Group.  This is the same as a Cisco L2 port channel.  Your PC will need to support link-aggregation and preferably LACP.  This link provides some info on setting it up: http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0117330